# Dropdown HTML e CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: <code>inserir a descrição da imagem aqui</code>]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    paddin: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    paddin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96B92B;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #053559;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .3s;
}  

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96B92B;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Cloud</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
   <span>Cloud</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Users <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="">All Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Send a Plan</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Ban User</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
   </ul>
   <button class="sidebarBtn">
    <span></span>
   </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer um dropdown com o user não sei o porque

Comment: Você já fez o código *JavaScript* ?

Comment: não, porque eu tentei e não foi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes faltou você esconder o dropdown no CSS com

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Em seguida você pode usar um evento de click para mostrar/esconder o dropdown.

### Usando JS puro (sem efeito slide)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var drops = document.body.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
   for(var x=0; x<drops.length; x++){
      drops[x].onclick = function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); // cancela a ação do link
         var ul = this.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
         ul.style.display = !ul.style.display || ul.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
         
         var seta = this.querySelector("span.fa");
         
         // alterar a setinha
         seta.classList.remove(ul.style.display == "block" ? "fa-angle-down" : "fa-angle-up");
         seta.classList.add(ul.style.display == "block" ? "fa-angle-up" : "fa-angle-down");
      }
   }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    paddin: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    paddin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96B92B;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #053559;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .3s;
}  

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96B92B;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
      <span>Cloud</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Users <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-content">
                  <li><a href="">All Users</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Send a Plan</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Ban User</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>

      </ul>
      <button class="sidebarBtn">
          <span></span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Usando jQuery (com efeito slide)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(".dropdown").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".dropdown-content", this).slideToggle(function(){
         $(this).parent().find("span").toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
      });
   });
   
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    paddin: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    paddin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96B92B;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #053559;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .3s;
}  

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96B92B;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
      <span>Cloud</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Users <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-content">
                  <li><a href="">All Users</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Send a Plan</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Ban User</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>

      </ul>
      <button class="sidebarBtn">
          <span></span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Está pegando agora, obrigado !